# View updates too late in Collection View after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview

I have CollectionView with image inside each cell.
When I'm scrolling this collection, new cell (indexPath = 10) contains image from old cell (indexPath = 1), then calls this method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

}
```

and I set image URL to new view.
What is the best way to hide old image after scrolling before update?

Comment: Are you downloading images from url ?

Comment: Try to set image to nil before requesting a new one with ulr. This way it will be empty until image is received from server

Comment: Its due to reuse of the cell. Can you pls post the code for `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`

Comment: Async images work like tihs, you can only use placeholder untill it loads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clean the images in the CollectionViewCell upon reusing them.
Override the `prepareForReuse` function in the CollectionViewCell subclass.

```
  override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        // Set the cell's imageView's image to nil
        self.imageView.image = nil
    }
```

Comment: Please do note that this method is available from iOS 8 onwards, previously this had to done by the programmer after dequeing the cell

Comment: @RohanBhale This is not true. CollectionView's are available since iOS6, and the function `prepareForReuse` is also available since iOS6.  Please see screenshot taken for the API documentation http://imgur.com/a/DjEjo

Comment: @dirtydanee UICollectionReusableView available fro iOS 6 onwards, the method was available fro iOS 8  onwards

Comment: @RohanBhale this is not true according to the documentation.

Comment: @dirtydanee I say it specifically for swift as the code in question is in swift